# Populate std::deque<std::vector<std::string>> with boost::assign::list_of

Tags: c++, boost, c++98

Is it possible to initialize objects of the type:

```
std::deque<std::vector<std::string>>
```

via boost::assign::list_of

Comment: If your compiler supports C++11 initializer lists, you could do e.g. `std::deque<std::vector<std::string>> deq = { { "foo", "bar" }, { "other", "list" } };`

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg My compiler doesn't support C++11

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
#include <boost/assign/list_of.hpp>
#include <deque>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::deque<std::vector<std::string> > v =
        boost::assign::list_of
            (boost::assign::list_of("a")("b"))
            (boost::assign::list_of("c")("d"));

    std::cout << v[0][0] << "\n" <<
                 v[1][1] << "\n";
}
```

*This compiled with the oldest compiler I have available VC7 so not C++98.*